# Docker: clean build context - where is the location Docker daemon stores build context on windows?

Tags: windows, docker

Docker: where is the location Docker daemon stores build context on windows?

When building an image, docker transfers all files under build context to Docker daemon.

```
transferring context: 755.30MB 7.9s
```

Which directory is it transferred to before building image?

When building with --no-cache

```
[internal] load build context
transferring context: 879.2kB 1.2s done
```

Build context is cached. How to clean build context on Daemon side?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to clear all build cache state with:

```
docker builder prune -a
```

```bash
$ docker builder prune --help

Usage:  docker buildx prune

Remove build cache

Options:
  -a, --all                  Include internal/frontend images
      --builder string       Override the configured builder instance (default "default")
      --filter filter        Provide filter values (e.g., "until=24h")
  -f, --force                Do not prompt for confirmation
      --keep-storage bytes   Amount of disk space to keep for cache
      --verbose              Provide a more verbose output
```

However, the exact algorithm for how the Docker build context works is quite complex.

You should also be able to find the actual director the Docker daemon will use with:

```bash
$ docker info | grep Root
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
```

Note that exactly how and where things are organized from there depend on several factors such as which storage driver you are using.

In general, you can use a `.dockerignore` file to control what is included in a given Docker context.

Comment: Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker, not found on windows 11 WSL, and /var/lib/docker-desktop is empty. thanks.